# data insertion works but not showing alertbox message

Tags: javascript, php, input

i have tried below code to execute validation function and the data insertion operation the followed code runs correctly on chrome but firefox not showing the message of succesfully insertion..

```
<input type="submit" onclick="chk()";/>//chk() contains validations
<?
  php

  if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
     data insertion code

    if(true)
    {
     <script language="javascript">alert " Adverties    added";window.location="adverties.php";</script>
    }

  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put JS in echo:

echo '.. script ... JS code';

2. I don't know if it's stackoverflow mistake, but **" Adv.. "** text is not in **( )**

So it should be:

```
if(true)
{
 echo '<script language="javascript">alert(" Adverties    added");window.location="adverties.php";</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working.

```
<form action="[name of the page]" method="post">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" onclick="chk()"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if(true){
        echo'<script> alert("Adverties added");window.location = "adverties.php";</script >';
    }
}
?>
```

so I put the `<input>` inside a `<form>` that redirects you to the current page and used the `POST` method.

You also have to use the `name` property inside of the `input` tag inorder for `$_POST["submit"]` to work, I also added the `echo` to print the JavaScript correctly.

I hope this solves your problems.

p.s. sorry for my bad enlish :)